# How to capture errors on telethon event coroutines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

I use the following script to listen for new messages from public telegram channels and groups.

```
import configparser
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
from telethon.tl.types import (
PeerChannel
)

api_id = 'xxxxxx'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

#target channels that you want to listen to:
input_channels = ('https://t.me/xxxxxx','https://t.me/xxxx','https://t.me/xxxxxxx')

#create a client
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

# Listen to messages from target channels 
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input_channels)) 
async def newMessageListener(event):
    # Get message text 
    newMessage = event.message.message 

    print(newMessage)


with client: 
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

When a channel is closed I get the following error: **ValueError: No user has "closed_channel_name" as username** and I stop receiving any data.

Is there a way to identify invalid channels?

So far I have found the following which could identify a valid channel but there might be a better way:

```
client.start()
result = client.get_entity('https://t.me/xxxxxx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for catching errors (inside a coroutine) on telethon

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

session_name = 'anon'
api_id = 'xxxxxx'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

chat_list = ('https://t.me/xxxxxxxx', 'https://t.me/xxxxxxxxxx')


async def main():
    async with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
        @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat_list))
        async def handler(event):
            print(event.message.message)

        await client.run_until_disconnected()


def custom_exception_handler(loop, context):
    # first, handle with default handler
    loop.default_exception_handler(context)

    exception = context.get('exception')
    if isinstance(exception, ValueError):
        print(context['exception'])
        loop.stop()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Set custom handler
loop.set_exception_handler(custom_exception_handler)
loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()
```